# Create multiple files in GitHub and commit via a single commit without cloning repo locally

Tags: python, git, github, python-3.8, pygithub

I was looking at the documentation for creating a file in GitHub using PyGitHub: https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html However, it creates a commit for each file.

In my use case, I will have several files to create and would prefer to commit them once instead of individual commits.

Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Comment: Use Git locally. Don't rely too much on GitHub web interface - that's not how you're supposed to use Git.